# Value of c so that $c(2-|x|-|y|)$ is a probability distribution function(see picture)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

Hint: Use the formula of volume of pyaramid.

My approach: I know that the integral of a pdf from $-\infty to +\infty$ gives you $1$. I tried taking the double integral, but got stuck in as how to evaluate the absolute value and use the volume of pyramid.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the pdf supposed to be defined over the larger square, or the smaller square in the picture?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 The smaller square, which looks like a diamond.

Comment: Are the vertices of the smaller square $(2,0), (0,2), (-2,0), (0,-2)$ or $(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)$? The first set of vertices would make more sense (as the volume under the surface $z = c(2-|x|-|y|)$ over that square does look like a pyramid), but from the picture you gave us, it seems like the smaller square's vertices is the second set of points.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Sorry, my bad. I understood the question wrong. The vertices of the smaller square is $(2,0), (0,2), (-2,0), (0,-2)$

Comment: @Rishris can you find two functions $y=f_1(x)$ and $y=f_2(x)$ whose graphs give you the top and bottom of the diamond?

Comment: I think you meant probability density function rather than probability distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

To move forward with this (correct) approach, you need to see (better yet, construct):

1)  The graph of the function $|x|+|y| = \mbox{const.}$ in the $xy$-plane.  (E.g., see the illustration for the case $||x||_{1}$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere

2)  The graph of the function $f(x,y) = \mbox{const} - (|x|+|y|)$.  This graph is the "top surface" of a pyramid, whose volume (from height $f=0$ to upper vertex) can be found by a well-known formula.  The only thing left to do is then to normalize your constant $c$ to make that volume equal $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you graph $f(x,y) = c(2-|x|-|y|)$ over the region $|x|+|y| \le 2$ (i.e. the square with vertices $(2,0), (0,2), (-2,0), (0,-2)$), then you get a pyramid shape.

The base of the pyramid is the square with vertices $(2,0), (0,2), (-2,0), (0,-2)$. The height of the pyramid is $f(0,0)$. The formula for the volume of a pyramid is $$\text{Volume} = \dfrac{1}{3}(\text{Base Area}) \cdot (\text{height}).$$

So, first find the base area and the height. Then, use the above formula to find the volume of the pyramid (in terms of $c$). Finally, figure out what value of $c$ makes that volume $1$.

Comment: In this case, won't c will simply be 1/volume or do we need to take the double integral to find the value of c?